# Teradata error 9124 Segmentation Violation in AMP

Tags: teradata

I am getting below error while running bteq in Teradata.
Teradata error 9124 Segmentation Violation in AMP.
Please do not resubmit the last request.

Can anyone please let me know what does above error mean.

Answer (score 1):

It means `Please do not resubmit the last request` :-)

This query caused an severe internal error which should be fixed. Contact your DBA to open an incident with Teradata support.